# Rails customer specific preferences on model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I have a many-to-many relationship between two models: Customers and Products. Many customers share the same database of products.

My questions is, what if I want to store Customer specific data for each product. Like how many are in stock? My first instinct is to create some kind of wrapper model (e.g. Inventory) that refers to a product but would be customer specific. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using a [has many through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

Comment: @AlthafHamez I don't think I'll need to access the product directly without the inventory information. So maybe a direct route is better than `through`?

Comment: @AlthafHamez the more I research the more I realize `through` is the best way to do it. Feel free to leave an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glad I could be of help.

Original Answer:
Have you considered using a [has many through association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)